# Contact Form 7 labels missing in REST

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form fetched using the endpoint e.g.: `/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/161`

In the admin, the template is defined as follows:

```
<label> Nom
  [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Adresse e-mail
  [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Message
  [textarea* your-message] </label>

[submit "Envoyer"]
```

The problem is that the labels are missing, or rather, they are only available within the `content` property.

The `labels` property is filled for the submit button, but it makes no sense to me why they make it available on the submit button. Semantically, I would have thought that is its `value`.

Is there some configuration I am missing to make this REST response more useful, or am I going to have to parse the content?

```
{
  id: 161,
  slug: "contact-form",
  title: "Formulaire de contact",
  locale: "en_US",
  properties: {
    form: {
      content: "<label> Nom\n  [text* your-name] </label>\n\n<label> Adresse e-mail\n  [email* your-email] </label>\n\n<label> Message\n  [textarea* your-message] </label>\n\n[submit \"Envoyer\"]",
      fields: [
        {
          type: "text*",
          basetype: "text",
          name: "your-name",
          options: [],
          raw_values: [],
          labels: [],
          values: [],
          pipes: [],
          content: ""
        },
        {
          type: "email*",
          basetype: "email",
          name: "your-email",
          options: [],
          raw_values: [],
          labels: [],
          values: [],
          pipes: [],
          content: ""
        },
        {
          type: "textarea*",
          basetype: "textarea",
          name: "your-message",
          options: [],
          raw_values: [],
          labels: [],
          values: [],
          pipes: [],
          content: ""
        },
        {
          type: "submit",
          basetype: "submit",
          name: "",
          options: [],
          raw_values: [
            "Envoyer"
          ],
          labels: [
            "Envoyer"
          ],
          values: [
            "Envoyer"
          ],
          pipes: [
            [
              "Envoyer",
              "Envoyer"
            ]
          ],
          content: ""
        }
      ]
    },
    mail: {},
    mail_2: {},
    messages: {},
    additional_settings: {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels don't seem to be what you think they are. It seems to be representing the default value according to the *Form tag generator*. With this in mind, I will simply use the default value to represent the label when consuming CF7 from an API.

```
[text* your-name "Nom"]
[email* your-email "Adresse Email"]
[textarea* your-message "Message"]
[submit "Envoyer"]
```